# Find Lowest Command Ancestor fail on tree search (Not algorithm issue, but more a Java issue)

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, divide-and-conquer

Very simple tree problem, somehow the result is null (which should be 1, since 1 is 2 & 3's parent node), cannot find the cause. The method itself already pass the Leetcode online judge.

Here is the link to the problem:

https://leetcode.com/problems/lowest-common-ancestor-of-a-binary-tree/

Given a binary tree, find the lowest common ancestor (LCA) of two given nodes in the tree.

According to the definition of LCA on Wikipedia: “The lowest common ancestor is defined between two nodes v and w as the lowest node in T that has both v and w as descendants (where we allow a node to be a descendant of itself).”

```
public class LowestCommonAncestor2 {

    public static TreeNode mockTree() {
        TreeNode node1 = new TreeNode(1);
        TreeNode node2 = new TreeNode(2);
        TreeNode node3 = new TreeNode(3);
        node1.left = node2;
        node1.right = node3;
        return node1;
    }

    public TreeNode lowestCommonAncestor(TreeNode root, TreeNode t1, TreeNode t2) {
           if (root == null || root == t1 || root == t2) {
               return root;
           }

           TreeNode left = lowestCommonAncestor(root.left, t1, t2);
           TreeNode right = lowestCommonAncestor(root.right, t1, t2);

           if (left != null && right != null) 
               return root;
           if (left != null) 
               return left;
           if (right != null) 
               return right;
           return null;
    }

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        LowestCommonAncestor2 test = new LowestCommonAncestor2();
        TreeNode root = mockTree();
        TreeNode target1 = new TreeNode(2);
        TreeNode target2 = new TreeNode(3);
        TreeNode result = test.lowestCommonAncestor(root, target1, target2);
        System.out.println(result);
    } 
}
```

and the TreeNode are defined as following:

```
public class TreeNode {
     public int val;
     public TreeNode left, right;
     public TreeNode(int val) {
         this.val = val;
         this.left = this.right = null;
     }
}
```

Comment: is it required that a TreeNode doesn't have a pointer to Parent ?

Comment: This is the TreeNode provide by the Leetcode, so I dont think pointer is a option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is happening because of this line of code

```
if (root == null || root == t1 || root == t2)
```

Think about exactly what you are comparing when executing this method

```
TreeNode result = test.lowestCommonAncestor(root, target1, target2);
```

When you call the LCA method, none of the conditions in the first if statement will evaluate to true because none of the statements are true, which is correct. However, now let's get to the first recursive calls,

```
TreeNode left = lowestCommonAncestor(root.left, t1, t2);
TreeNode right = lowestCommonAncestor(root.right, t1, t2);
```

For `lowestCommonAncestor(root.left, t1, t2)`, carefully think about the first if statement. `root` in this case is now `node2`, while t1 and t2 are still the nodes `target1` and `target2` defined in the main like before. But wait, this is why the problem is occurring. You would expect the statement `root == t1` to evaluate to true, but it's not evaluating to true and here's why. `node2` and `target1` are two different objects, and Java's `==` operator doesn't do what you think it does here. When comparing objects using the `==` operator, the addresses of the objects are being compared rather than the actual contents of the objects. Therefore, since `node2` and `target1` occupy different spaces of data in your program, they do not have the same addresses. You will see the `==` operator more commonly used for comparing primitive types in Java such as int and char because it's not the same as comparing objects. This is why you see the `.equals` method used to compare Strings in Java, because Strings are objects.

**So what's the solution?**

Make an `equals` method in your TreeNode class that returns a boolean and takes another TreeNode object as a parameter. Also, make sure that this method is an instance method rather than a static method so that the execution of this method in code looks like this,

```
public boolean equals(TreeNode node){ //method address
    //rest of the method has to be implemented yourself
    //ask yourself, how are two treenodes considered equal in your situation?
}
```

And lastly, replace `root == t1` with

```
root.equals(t1)
```

and `root == t2` with

```
root.equals(t2)
```

Comment: You are right, I neglected that I was trying to compare two objects. So, I think the easiest way is change if (root == null || root == t1 || root == t2)  into if (root == null || root.val == t1.val || root.val == t2.val)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
public TreeNode lowestCommonAncestor(TreeNode root, TreeNode t1, TreeNode t2) {
       if((search(root,t1)==null)||(search(root,t2)==null)
           return null;           
       if(search(root.left,t1)!=null)
       {          
           if(search(root.left,t2)!=null)
              return lowestCommonAncestor(root.left,t1,t2);
       }
       else if(search(root.right,t2)!=null)            
           return lowestCommonAncestor(root.right,t1,t2);
       return root;                                   
}
```

`search` method searches a TreeNode inside a Tree, I'll leave that for you ;).

### Explanation

First we check if `root` tree contains the node `t1` and `t2`, if `root` doesn't contain one of them we return null as there is no ancestor.

After that we search for `t1` in `root.left`, if we find it we search for `t2` in `root.left`, if we find it then the least common ancestor must be in `root.left` but we can't determine it yet so we recursively call the method with `lowestCommonAncestor(root.left,t1,t2)`.

Now if we found `t2` in right and found `t1` in right then the least common ancestor is in `right` and we recursively call.

In all other cases we return root because `t1` is in left and `t2` is in right or vice versa, in both cases root is a common ancestor(because of our check)so it's the least common ancestor.

If we were allowed to have a `parent` pointer in every `TreeNode` , a better algorithm is to walk up the tree from `t1.parent` and only stop when `p=t1.parent`(or `t1.parent.parent`, you got the idea) is an ancestor of `t2`.